# How to filter literal as well as space-less sentence in Django?

Tags: django

The code below describes search function in my website. Let's say there is a business named "Los Angeles"; then I want to get the location with the search text "Losangeles".

With actual code if I type "los", "angeles", or "los angeles" as `search_text`, it finds "Los Angeles", but "losangeles" can't. Is there any way to let me do that in Django views?

```
class SearchListView(ListView):

  def get_queryset(self):

          search_text = self.request.GET.get('search_text')

          if search_text:
              search_stores = Store.objects.filter(location__icontains=search_text)

          return search_stores.filter(status='active')
```

Comment: Are you asking why the filter is failing when you use the term "LosAngeles" to search for "Los Angeles"? That seems to be pretty obvious. Why would Django assume you meant a space or smash all the words in your target text field together and try to find your misspelled string? A terrible option would be to replace all the spaces in your target with a blank string and then do your filter.

Comment: My client asked me if it's possible to search with a keyword with any space. He showed me some other website that let people search with keywords without any space. So,  I came to ask this question.

Comment: @dfundako I think that's a good idea removing all spaces in my target and checking if the target contains the keyword. Is it a bad practice?

Comment: Did you consider full text search? If you're using postgres, django support [full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/). You can use trigram similarity with using pg_trgm.

Comment: @seuling Unfortunately, currently using MySQL, but planning to switch it to Postgres later. Thank you for the recommendation!

Comment: good to helping you. I really recommend full text search - it's a fantastic experience for me. For mysql, you can consider elasticsearch too.